# Unscoped Enumeration, Enumerator & Underlying Type Ambiguity in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, enums, c++17

I was going through the C++ standard n4713.pdf. Consider below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum UEn
{
    EN_0,
    EN_1,
    EN_L = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF            // EN_L has type "long int"
};                                       // UEn has underlying type "unsigned long int"

int main()
{
    long lng = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "typeof(unsigned long == UEn):" << std::is_same<unsigned long, std::underlying_type<UEn>::type>::value << std::endl;  // Outputs "true"
    std::cout << "sizeof(EN_L):" << sizeof(EN_L) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(unsigned):" << sizeof(unsigned) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(unsigned long):" << sizeof(unsigned long) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(unsigned long):" << sizeof(unsigned long long) << std::endl;

    lng = EN_L + 1;                      // Invokes UB as EN_L is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and has type "long int"

    return 0;
}
```

The above code outputs (tested on g++-8.1, Clang):

`typeof(unsigned long == UEn):true` `sizeof(EN_L):8` `sizeof(unsigned):4` `sizeof(unsigned long):8` `sizeof(unsigned long):8`

As per Section 10.2p5 (10.2 Enumeration declarations):

> Following the closing brace of an enum-specifier, each enumerator has
>   the type of its enumeration...If the underlying type is not fixed, the
>   type of each enumerator prior to the closing brace is determined as
>   follows:
>
> - If an initializer is specified for an enumerator, the
>     constant-expression shall be an integral constant expression (8.6). If
>     the expression has unscoped enumeration type, the enumerator has the
>     underlying type of that enumeration type, otherwise it has the same
>     type as the expression.
> - If no initializer is specified for the first
>     enumerator, its type is an unspecified signed integral type.
> - Otherwise the type of the enumerator is the same as that of the
>     preceding enumerator unless the incremented value is not representable
>     in that type, in which case the type is an unspecified integral type
>     sufficient to contain the incremented value. If no such type exists,
>     the program is ill-formed.

Further, section 10.2p7 states:

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying
>   type is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values
>   defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the
>   enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. It is
>   implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying
>   type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int
>   unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned
>   int.

Thus I have following questions:

1. Why is the underlying type of enum `UEn` an `unsigned long` when  `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is an integer constant of type `long int` and thus type of `EN_L` is also `long int`. Is this a compiler bug or well defined behaviour?
2. When the standard says **`each enumerator has the type of its enumeration`**, shouldn't it imply that the integral types of enumerator and enumeration should also match? What could be the reason in having these two different from each other?

Comment: 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is an integral constant of indeterminated signed-ness. Your compiler chose to store it as an `unsigned long`.

Comment: @JonHarper: The standard says:  _"The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 7 in which its value can be represented: Binary, octal, or hexadecimal literal - int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, unsigned long long int"._   Compiler can't act on its whim, can it?

Comment: A conforming compiler *can* act on its whim in certain cases (UB, unspecified behavior), but otherwise you are correct. Compilers are rarely, if ever, truly conformant, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying type is implementation-defined. It only has to be able to represent every enumerator, and it can't be larger than `int` unless required. There is no requirement on signedness (aside that the base type has to be able to represent every enumerator), per [dcl.enum.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#7), as you already found. This limits the back-propagation of enumerators' types more than you appear to assume. Notably, it doesn't say anywhere that the base type of the enum has to be the type of any of the enumerators' initializer.

Clang prefers unsigned integers as enum bases over signed integers; that's all there is to it. Importantly, the type of the enum does not have to match any specific enumerator's type: it only has to be able to represent every enumerator. This is fairly normal and well-understood in other contexts. For instance, if you had `EN_1 = 1`, it wouldn't surprise you that the enum's base type isn't `int` or `unsigned int`, even though 1 is an `int`.

You are also correct in saying that the type of `0x7fffffffffffffff` is `long`. Clang agrees with you, however it [implicitly casts the constant to `unsigned long`](https://godbolt.org/z/CmFXn0):

```
TranslationUnitDecl
`-EnumDecl <line:1:1, line:5:1> line:1:6 Foo
  |-EnumConstantDecl <line:2:5> col:5 Frob 'Foo'
  |-EnumConstantDecl <line:3:5> col:5 Bar 'Foo'
  `-EnumConstantDecl <line:4:5, col:11> col:5 Baz 'Foo'
    `-ImplicitCastExpr <col:11> 'unsigned long' <IntegralCast>
      `-IntegerLiteral <col:11> 'long' 576460752303423487
```

This is allowed, because as we said before, the enumeration's base type doesn't need to be the verbatim type of any enumerator.

When the standard says that each enumerator has the type of the enumeration, it means that the type of `EN_1` is `enum UEn` after the enum's closing brace. Note the "after the closing brace" and "prior to the closing brace" mentions.

Prior to the closing brace, if the enum has no fixed type, then the type of each enumerator is that of its initializing expression type, but this is only temporary. This is what allows you, for instance, to write `EN_2 = EN_1 + 1` without casting `EN_1`, even in the scope of an `enum class`. This is no longer true after the closing brace. You can trick the compiler into showing you by inspecting error messages or by looking at disassembly:

```
template<typename T>
T tell_me(const T&& value);

enum Foo {
    Baz = 0x7ffffffffffffff,
    Frob = tell_me(Baz)
    // non-constexpr function 'tell_me<long>' cannot be used in a constant expression
};
```

Notice that in this case `T` was inferred to be `long`, but after the closing brace, it's inferred to be `Foo`:

```
template<typename T>
T tell_me(const T&& value);

enum Foo {
    Baz = 0x7ffffffffffffff
};

int main() {
    tell_me(Baz);
    // call    Foo tell_me<Foo>(Foo const&&)
}
```

If you want your enum type to be signed with Clang, you need to specify it using the `: base_type` syntax, or you need to have a negative enumerator.

Comment: Negative enumeration values are nice for indicating error codes anyways. Whenever I make a new Enum, I always specify `error = -1` as the first entry. Later you can compare `if code > SomeEnum::error`. However, it is a good idea to use the `: base_type` syntax to avoid arithmetic logic errors between signed and unsigned types, like you suggest. It would be confusing if there were some signed and some unsigned enums, in the case of enums without negative values defined.

Comment: @zneak I agree, however the point that I was trying to bring about is that even though all the enumerators could fit into long, the compiler would explicitly impose unsigned type on the enumeration. Wouldn't it make sense to keep the type same as the type of the enumerators as long as it couldn't fit them. To top it, both GCC and Clang have the same behaviour. Well, I guess if the standard says it is implementation defined, the point is moot! Btw, +1 for the trick with the templates!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer for this (admittedly unintuitive) warning is in 7.6 Integral promotions [conv.prom]:

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not
>   fixed (10.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the
>   following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration
>   (i.e., the values in the range b<sub>min</sub> to b<sub>max</sub> as described in 10.2):
>   `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, or
>   `unsigned long long int`.

I.e., if your underlying type is not fixed, and you use an enumeration member in an expression, it doesn't necessarily convert to the enumeration's underlying type.  It instead converts to the first type in that list in which all members fit.

Don't ask me why, the rule seems nuts to me.

This section goes on to say:

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
>   fixed (10.2) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type.

I.e. if you fix the underlying type with `unsigned long`:

```
enum UEn : unsigned long
...
```

then the warning goes away.

Another way to get rid of the warning (and leave the underlying type not fixed) is to add a member which requires `unsigned long` storage:

```
EN_2 = 0x8000000000000000
```

Then again, the warning goes away.

Good question.  I learned a lot in answering it.

Comment: So this means, the underlying type of an enum is fixed _only_ in following 2 cases - 1. Scoped enumeration 2. Unscoped with "enum base" qualifier, (Sec 10.2p5): _"Each enumeration also has an underlying type. The underlying type can be explicitly specified using an enum-base. For a scoped enumeration type, the underlying type is int if it is not explicitly specified. In both of these cases, the underlying type is said to be fixed"_. So, despite enum's underlying type being "unsigned", the "7.6 Integral promotions" causes the increment to be UB! Boy, I just don't know how to react. It's a mess!

Answer (score 0):

The wording of section 10.2p5 explicitly says "...prior to the closing brace..." suggests the following interpretation. The type of an enumerator **within the definition of the enum type** (before closing brace) is chosen to be some integral type large enough to represent its value. This value may then be reused in the definition of subsequent enumerators definition in the same enum. When the enum type closing brace is encountered, then the compiler chooses an integral type large enough to represent all enumerator values. After the definition of the enum type, all enumerator values have the same type (which is the enum type) and share the underlying type of the enum. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

enum E1
{
  e1 = 0, // type of the initializer (int), value = 0
  e2 = e1 + 1U, // type of the initializer (unsigned = int + unsigned), value = 1U
  e3 = e1 - 1, // type of the initializer (int = int - int), value = -1
}; // range of values [-1, 1], underlying type is int

int main()
{
   std::cout << typeid(std::underlying_type<E1>::type).name() << '\n';
   std::cout << typeid(e1).name() << '\n';
   std::cout << typeid(e2).name() << '\n';
   std::cout << typeid(e3).name() << '\n';
}
```

Ran with clan5 and gcc8 and it outputs:

```
i
2E1
2E1
2E1
```